# UICollectionView with multiple rows

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I use UICollectionView (views with UIButtons) to book the time:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        collectionViewTime.register(UINib(nibName: "TimeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "timecell")
        collectionViewTime.dataSource = self
        collectionViewTime.delegate = self        
        if let layout = collectionViewTime.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        }

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Timeline.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {            
        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let numberOfItems = CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))
        let combinedItemWidth = (numberOfItems * flowLayout.itemSize.width) + ((numberOfItems - 1)  * flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)
        let padding = (collectionView.frame.width - combinedItemWidth) / 2
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: padding, bottom: 0, right: padding)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {            
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timecell", for: indexPath) as! TimeCollectionViewCell            
        let time = Timeline[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.btnTime.setTitle(DateManager.dateToTime(date: time.0), for: .normal)            
        return cell
    }
```

And I got all views (UIButtons) in one line:
[image: UICollectionView]
How can I set automatically moving UIViews in new rows?
So, in my case (iPad) one row will contain 7 UIViews, iPhone will contain 4-5 UIViews in one row.

Comment: UICollectionView calculates it width and cell width keeping offsets in mind, so say if width of UICollectionView is 320, and one cell is 200, it will show one below another, so you need to adjust the width that way the way you want it to show cells. If you want to show side by side in that case two cells width should accomodate in total width of UICollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` and change the `collectionView`'s `Scroll direction` to `Vertical`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let minCellSpace: CGFloat = 10 //Set minimum cell space that you want
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
         //For iPad return 7 cell as you mention in question
         return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width / 7) - minCellSpace, height: yourCellHeight)
    }
    else {
         //For iPhone return 4 cell, if you want to return 5 cell divide width to 5
         return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.size.width / 4) - minCellSpace, height: yourCellHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this method, it called, but views are not moved on the new rows

Comment: @Kirill You need to set collectionView scroll direction to vertical not horizontal

Comment: please see my code above. I wrote layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

Comment: @Kirill Put the print statement in `if let` block where you setting direction to vertical and check it is printing in console. If it is printing in console then you need to increase the `collectionview` height, because if you scroll the collectionView it will show you the cell in new line.

Comment: I checked, it printed in console. I added collectionViewTime.frame.size.height = 300 (height of my cells = 45), but it doesn't work too

Comment: @Kirill reload the collectionView after changing the direction because you are setting delegate and datasorce before it.

Comment: I added collectionViewTime.reloadData(), it doesn't work. collectionViewTime contains one row only

Comment: @Kirill Can you edit your question with code that you are currently trying.

Comment: It worked! I removed function with "return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: padding, bottom: 0, right: padding)"

Answer (score 0):

Please use one more flow delegate method as below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize;
------
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:(button width), height:button hieght);
    }
```